# Word choice between will and would

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

> Sometimes rules may not have a positive influence on children if those parents who set strict rules focus too much on children's obedience. Children **will/would** rely heavily on rules and may not be able to solve problems independently.

Which word should I use here? I think they are both acceptable but there is a difference in meaning; **will** is more affirmative while **would** is more tentative; **will** is like describing a fact whereas **would** is giving a personal opinion. Am I right?

Comment: Yep, you're totally, 100% right on that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. "Would" would imply a hypothetical or an uncertainty, as in

> I would take the red pill.

whereas "will" is definite, as in

> I will take the blue pill.

In this scenario I would use "will".